# Remote validations gem for formtastic and Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rubygems, formtastic

I using Formtastic, and is awesome!
I can use Formtastic with `remote: true` option but if I do that I lose validations results =/

So I was wondering if there is a gem that can manage remote validations and work with Formtastic?

I've found some, but are very outdated (like a year or more) and unlikely to work with Rails 3 or Formtastic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in essence you are not losing your validations. They are still being performed, but you are just not able to see their result, like you normally do without `remote: true`.

You can try using [client_side_validations](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations). It will show results as you fill in your fields and move on to next. Most amazing thing it supports Formtastic

Railscasts have a excellent [screencasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations) to help you out with it.

Comment: if you think, this answer matches very closely with what you are looking, then, don't forget to accept it as right answer

Comment: I know the validations are performed anyway, but is kind of pointless :P
Anyway, I will check it out right now! ^^

Comment: Because you don't give feedback to the user to know the object didn't validated.
Anyway, I'm using client_side_validations right now ^^